# Solving for integer M: $\frac{M}{M-1}c^M \leq \frac{\delta}{NT}$ where $c = \Phi(1)$ and $1>\delta>0$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

I am trying to prove a high probability bound and that reduces to finding a positive integer $M$ that would satisfy the following inequality. In the inequality $c = \Phi(1)$ where $\Phi$ denotes the cumulative density function of standard normal distribution, $ 1> \delta > 0$, and $N$ and $T$ are constant integers. Any suggestion how I can approach it?

$$\frac{M}{M-1}c^M \leq \frac{\delta}{NT}$$

Answer (score 0):

I ma afraid that you will need some numerical method for solving the problem.

Let $k=\frac{\delta}{NT}$ and you need to solve first
$$\frac{M}{M-1}c^M =k$$ which can rewrite as 
$$e^{-M \log(c)}=\frac 1 k \frac M{M-1}$$ and you face the problem of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

I should set the problem as : find the zero of function
$$f(M)=M\log(c)-\log \left(1-\frac{ 1}{M}\right)-\log(k)$$ and start Newton iteration with $M_0=\frac{\log (k)}{\log (c)}$.

If $M$ is supposed to be large, make a series expansion to get
$$f(M)=M \log (c)+\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{2 M^2}+\frac{1}{3
   M^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{M^4}\right)$$ and use series reversion fo get, as an *approximation*,
$$M=\frac{z}{\log (c)}-\frac{1}{z}-\frac{\log (c)}{2 z^2}-\frac{\log (c) (\log
   (c)+3)}{3 z^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^4}\right)\quad \text{where} \quad z=\log(k)$$